# how to add margins to FlowPanel?

Tags: gwt

I'm using com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel
Widgets are very close to each other.
However I can't figure out how to set margins?

BTW probably there are better layouts? I just need a container for several Anchors that located one by one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it either programmatically :

`flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("margin", "10px");`

Or with a CSS class that declares a margin (`YourCssClassWithMargin{ margin: 10px; }`) :

-> if you use UiBinder add the CSS style this way :

```
<g:FlowPanel styleName='YourCssClassWithMargin'>
```

-> if you don't use UiBinder this way :

`flowPanel.addStyleName("YourCssClassWithMargin");`

Comment: i've tried that `flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("margin", "10px");`. This do different thing. This code adds space in the border of flowpanel. But I need to add space *between widgets* inside flowPanel

Comment: ok when I add margin to `anchor` instead of `flowPanel` I have almost what I want. But this code adds both vertical and horizontal margins. I need only horizontal margin, I do not need vertical margin - is that possible?

Comment: Yes use marginLeft and/or marginRight instead of just margin.

Answer (score 3):

New Methods has been added with all the property elements as separate methods. This comes very handy like

```
`flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMargin(10, Unit.PX);`
`flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMarginLeft(10, Unit.PX);`
`flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMarginRight(10, Unit.PX);`
`flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMarginTop(10, Unit.PX);`
`flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMarginBottom(10, Unit.PX);`
```

Answer (score 0):

The easist way would be using the [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) CSS has.

If you would like to apply a `margin` to all `Anchors` in all `Divs`(A `FlowPanel` is a normal `Div`) you use this CSS:

```
div a {
   margin:10px;
}
```

If you would like to apply the `margin` only to the `Anchor` in your `FlowPanel` you would to something like this:

```
.FlowPanelStyle {
    margin:10px;
}
```

You would have to apply the `FlowPanelStyle` to your `FlowPanel` by calling

> yourFlowPanel.addStyleName("FlowPanelStyle");